# How to change file permissions in a Yeoman Generator?

Tags: yeoman-generator

I am writing a private yeoman generator package for use in my own organization, and my source code repository is not github, but our TF Source Code Control database.  When code is committed in a changeset to the database, the local workspace copy of any file is made read-only, which is part of how TFS can operate through visual studio.

This means that files that are committed to my source code control are sitting in my workspace as readonly files. For the files that are templates in my yeoman generator, if they are readonly, and I use them locally when testing the generator through npm link, the read-only attribute is copied along with the file to the destination file in the scaffolded project I am building.  Even, say, the package.json file.

Is there any way to tell yeoman generator to create all scaffolded files without the readonly bit set?  Or to unset that bit after the file copy?

Comment: +1. Same problem here with my team using TFS instead of Git (rip me please). The generators are a pain in the ass because you need to remove all read-only properties before using the generators. What a waste of time and energy.